# how to add systray image using pywin32

Tags: python

In the code, the default executable image is showing in taskbar systray. How can I assign an image of my choice in the taskbar systray? AFTER printing the iconPathName in console, it is showing the path where image is present, but image is not shown in task bar when i run the code

```
from win32api import *
from win32gui import *
import win32con
import sys, os
import struct
import time

class WindowsBalloonTip:
    def __init__(self, title, msg):
        message_map = {
                win32con.WM_DESTROY: self.OnDestroy,
        }
        # Register the Window class.
        wc = WNDCLASS()
        hinst = wc.hInstance = GetModuleHandle(None)
        wc.lpszClassName = "PythonTaskbar"
        wc.lpfnWndProc = message_map # could also specify a wndproc.
        classAtom = RegisterClass(wc)
        # Create the Window.
        style = win32con.WS_OVERLAPPED | win32con.WS_SYSMENU
        self.hwnd = CreateWindow( classAtom, "Taskbar", style, \
                0, 0, win32con.CW_USEDEFAULT, win32con.CW_USEDEFAULT, \
                0, 0, hinst, None)
        UpdateWindow(self.hwnd)
        iconPathName = os.path.abspath(os.path.join( sys.path[0], "cc.png" ))
        print iconPathName
        icon_flags = win32con.LR_LOADFROMFILE | win32con.LR_DEFAULTSIZE
        try:
            hicon = LoadImage(hinst, iconPathName, \
                    win32con.IMAGE_ICON, 0, 0, icon_flags)
        except:
            hicon = LoadIcon(0, win32con.IDI_APPLICATION)
        flags = NIF_ICON | NIF_MESSAGE | NIF_TIP
        nid = (self.hwnd, 0, flags, win32con.WM_USER+20, hicon, "cloud")
        Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_ADD, nid)
        Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_MODIFY, \
                         (self.hwnd, 0, NIF_INFO, win32con.WM_USER+20,\
                          hicon, "Balloon  tooltip",msg,200,title))
        # self.show_balloon(title, msg)
        time.sleep(10)
        DestroyWindow(self.hwnd)
    def OnDestroy(self, hwnd, msg, wparam, lparam):
        nid = (self.hwnd, 0)
        Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_DELETE, nid)
        PostQuitMessage(0) # Terminate the app.

def balloon_tip(title, msg):
    w=WindowsBalloonTip(title, msg)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    balloon_tip("Opening from cloud", "File open")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your icon is probably not in the right format. I believe you must use an `ICO` file instead of `PNG`. The rest of the code *looks* ok.

You should be able to see this problem if you remove the try/except block around `LoadImage` (or maybe it returns `None`?)